# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'unselectable' of null in VueJS-Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, ckeditor

I'm having a problem with CKEditor. It's very unstable. Sometimes it works, most times it doesn't. After reading some internet chatter, CKEditor does a poor job at sanitizing themselves and causes this error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'unselectable' of null`. Whatever that means :/ Bottom line is, it crashes a lot.

One solution I found was to add:

```
ckInstance.removeAllListeners();
CKEDITOR.remove(ckInstance);
```

Not sure where that should go so I added to the instantiation of CKEDITOR in app.balde.php, like so:

```
<script src="/vendor/unisharp/laravel-ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script>
  try{
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'article-ckeditor' )
    ckInstance.removeAllListeners();
    CKEDITOR.remove(ckInstance);
  }
  catch {

  };
</script>
```

That's not fixing it. Am I supposed to add this somewhere else? Or do you have any other ideas? Here's a kicker. If I add:

```
import CKEditor from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic";
Vue.use(CKEditor);
```

in the app.js file, it works, but lots of other stuff break everywhere. I'm not sure what gives.

Any help is appreciated